# List connection strings from external configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enterprise-library

In my **App.config**, I have a reference to an external configuration file, containing connection strings for **Enterprise Library**:

```
<enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="File Configuration Source">
    <sources>
        <add name="File Configuration Source" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
            filePath="\\path\to\my\Connections.config" />
    </sources>
</enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
```

Is there a way to list all connection strings in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app.config is just an XML file so you can use XDocument to open and parse it.

Comment: Care to add some guidance in your original post as to what specific methods would be acceptible ? Does it need to be done using Ent Lib ?

Comment: Your answer is acceptable, actually. It's just that I was looking for something more in the line of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`. I'll look into this in the next couple of days.